# Swift distinguishing between callout buttons

Tags: swift

Hi I'm mostly new to coding and this is my first project that I've worked on. I'm making an app that displays pools which are hiring around your address and wanted to make it so that pressing on the callouts will bring you to a unique ViewController depending on which one you pressed.

From what I've seen so far online it looks like it needs to be done in an extension of the ViewController but was stuck on how to differentiate between callouts (as of right now I have it so that pressing it will show the directions, but I'd rather show more information that just that, which to my limited knowledge would mean displaying another view controller unless anyone else has any other ideas)

```
extension MapViewController : MKMapViewDelegate
{
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    if let annotation = annotation as? Pools {
    let identifier = "pin"
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView =
            mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView{
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            view = dequeuedView
        }
        else {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIView
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let location = view.annotation as! Pools
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    location.mapItem().openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting an error or problem with the code above, or are you just wanting to add more information to annotations? That second delegate method could be used to navigate to another view controller.

Comment: There are no errors in the code, I just wanted to be able to display more information. I would be open to the second delegate method if you could outline it a bit for me, I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: you could store the info inside the _pools_ and when that is selected you pass that to new controller and display what you intend to